# preg_replace, where is the mistake?

Tags: php

I want to replace, in a dictionary, the letters that start with a vowel with an acute accent, by the letter a, but when I put 'á' it doesn't read it to me and therefore it doesn't replace it. How can I make the function read it to me that special character?

```
$letter_in_progress = 'área';
$pattern = '/á/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, 'a', $letter_in_progress);
```

Comment: works as expected : https://3v4l.org/i9m6L

Comment: Good job @Syscall

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove **any accents**, you can transliterate them to ASCII.

```
$letter_in_progress = 'área';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $letter_in_progress);
```

> `area`